# How to place the tooltip overlay so it is not clipped by the openlayers map

Tags: openlayers-3

[image: example of a tooltip that is clipped to the map borders]

In the screenshot, the tool tip overlay appears above the feature.  Because the feature is close to the map view border, it is clipped and only partially visible.

overlay = map.getOverlayById('tooltip');
  overlay.setPosition(evt.coordinate);

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily fixed by setting the autoPan: true option when the overlay is created.

Note that this does not move the tooltip window to be inside the map view, instead it pans the map view so that the tool tip is fully inside view.

A side-effect of autoPan is that the event to click or hover on a feature will cause the feature's marker to pan also, so it is no longer under the mouse.